# Conditions of the error of Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: numerical-methods

If $f\in C^2[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$,then exist $\xi \in (a,b)$,such that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=-\frac{1}{12}f''(\xi)(b-a)^3$ 
It is the error formula of trapezoidal rule and can be easily proved by partial integration or error formula of Lagrange's interpolation. 
What if we reduce the requirement of $f(x)$.$f(x)$ is twice differentiable(may not be continuous).The error formula still works but the two methods fail.How can I prove that then?

Comment: You mean that $f(x)^2$ is that smooth? How do you still get the same error formula if for instance the function switches sign in the middle  The function could be piecewise linear with non-zero integral, while the second derivative is zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think this is about $f$ being twice differentiable but $f''$ not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Then this could be an unfortunate sentence structure and not the line dot replacing the multiplication sign. Then one can still construct counter examples with piecewise quadratic polynomials.

Comment: In the error formula, if $f''$ isn't continuous, the conclusion is still right.But in that situation, $f''$ may not be Riemann integrable. So the previous methods don't work.

Comment: "the conclusion is still right." - how do you know that it is still right? Either you do not know it, in which case you should not be pretending that you do; or else you do know it, in which case you already have a proof available. Also, please recall that Riemann's is not the latest-and-greatest in definitions of the integral. For this, Henstock-Kurzweil would likely be the most useful.

Comment: It is actually an exercise of my analysis course but I don't know the solution. Riemann's theory isn't the latest but I just wonder how can I prove it in Riemann Integral.